# hover over a tag class change image src of img in different element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have something like this:

```
<div class="right">
<article class="left_image">
<img src="images/coolestimageontheplanet.jpg" class="image_left">
</article>
```

And then I have a UL list:

```
    <ul class="LISTS">
      <li><a href="#link" target="_blank" class="hov5">Link 1</a></li>
       <!-- etc -->
    </ul>
```

I would have about 10 list items in the directly above mark-up fashion. Based on hover class I would like to swap out the image source associated with `class="image_left"` as seen above. So hover over `class="hov5"` you get the *hov5 image*.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean by "get the hov5 image"? What determines what the "hov5 image" will be?

Comment: I guess class name determines image name (?!), but i suggest using of this nice feature: https://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add event listeners for mouseover & mouseleave and then change the image.src accordingly, like in such a way

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  function initImageHover(selector, displaySelector) {
    var imageContainer = document.querySelectorAll(displaySelector)[0],
      elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

    for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
      createHover(elements[i], imageContainer, imageContainer.src);
    };
  }

  function createHover(that, targetElement, originalImage) {

    that.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
      var src = that.getAttribute('data-src');
      if (src) {
        targetElement.src = src;
      }
    });
    that.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
      targetElement.src = originalImage;
    });
  }

  initImageHover('li > a', '.image_left');
});
```

```html
<div class="right">
  <article class="left_image">
    <img src="images/coolestimageontheplanet.jpg" class="image_left">
  </article>

  <ul class="LISTS">
    <li><a href="#link" target="_blank" class="hov1">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#link" target="_blank" class="hov2">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#link" target="_blank" class="hov3">Link 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#link" target="_blank" class="hov4">Link 4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#link" target="_blank" class="hov5">Link 5</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#link" target="_blank" class="hov6">Link 6</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#link" target="_blank" data-src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=a7723f5f7e59" class="hov7">Link 7</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, for this! I'm using this. One question, any way possible to on any mouse out return to original image source before the hover?

Comment: @YourConscious yes, you could also put a tag on the image and put it back in the `mouseleave` callback, in a similar way that is used inside the `mouseover` callback

Comment: Thanks, I guess i wasn't specific enough, original source is not where the hover data source is declared. Take a look here if you feel like you can help on this one! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846733/on-mouseleave-revert-image-back-to-origin-source-that-is-outside-where-hover-dat

Comment: @YourConscious I editted the answer above, it now also includes the reset, and from what I saw from the previous question, it can now also hold multiple source / target elements (so you don't have to duplicate all the code to support multiple li > a sources and/or target element sources)

Answer (score 1):

Add a data tag like so:

```
<ul class="LISTS">
      <li><a href="#link" target="_blank" class="hov5" data-img="images/newimg.jpg">Link 1</a></li>
       <!-- etc -->
```

Then use a code like this:

```
$("ul.LISTS>li").hover(function(){
     var imgurl = $(this).data("img");
     $(".image_left").attr("src",imgurl);
},
function(){ 
     $(".image_left").attr("src","images/coolestimageontheplanet.jpg");
});
```