# on mouseleave revert image back to origin source that is outside where hover data source is

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function createHover (that) {

  var original = document.getElementsByClassName("image_left"); // attempt

  that.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    var src = that.getAttribute('data-src');
    if (src) {
      imageContainer.src = src;
    }
  });
  that.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    // imageContainer.src = original;
  });
}

  initImageHover('li.one > a');
});
```

Mark-up:

```
<img src="images/grades_13.jpg" class="image_left">
```

Above is the image that changes. My code works on hover where this source is replaced with that of in below mark-up:

```
<ul class="LISTS">
     <li class="one"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="hov1" data-src="images/thumb1.jpg">Link</a></li>

<!-- test --->
```

But I need a mouse out function that returns to original source before any hover; the original source of `class="image_left"`

below is the full JS.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var imageContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.image_left')[0];

  function initImageHover(selector) {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    console.log(elements);
    for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
      createHover(elements[i]);
    };
  }

function createHover (that) {

  var original = document.getElementsByClassName("image_left");

  that.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    var src = that.getAttribute('data-src');
    if (src) {
      imageContainer.src = src;
    }
  });
  that.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    // imageContainer.src = original;
  });
}

  initImageHover('li.one > a');
});

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var imageContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.image_left2')[0];

  function initImageHover(selector) {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    console.log(elements);
    for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
      createHover(elements[i]);
    };
  }

function createHover (that) {

  var original = that.getAttribute('src');

  that.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    var src = that.getAttribute('data-src');
    if (src) {
      imageContainer.src = src;
    }
  });
  that.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    // imageContainer.src = original;
  });
}

  initImageHover('li.two > a');
});
```

Comment: don't duplicate your code like this, find the most common elements and abstract so when you have an error, you only have to redo a code fix on 5 places where you copy pasted your code for some small change. See your original question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832112/hover-over-a-tag-class-change-image-src-of-img-in-different-element/32832311#32832311

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var original = document.getElementsByClassName("image_left");` gives you an array of elements with the given class name. So you should first pull one element (or you should use `id` instead), and assign the source of that image.

```js
that.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
   var origImage = original.length && original[0].src; // assuming the element exists and is an image
    // or original[0].getAttribute("src") depending on whether you want the full source of image or exactly as defined in "src" attribute
   // imageContainer.src = origImage;
});
```

Comment: Yes but wont this look for the original source from which is li a where the hover source is at? The original source is not where the hover source is.

Comment: I see what you mean. You should be preserving the original image source and not the original element, because the element is a reference and can change when you update the element's property.  Here's what I would do: `var original = document.getElementsByClassName("image_left")[0].getAttribute("src");` and then in your `mouseleave` event, do `imageContainer.src = original`;